# how to pass variable in jquery .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a simple drop-down menu when the user selects any of the options, i want to be able to pass that selected value to a JavaScript function

Once the user clicks on an option it will alert the value in the jQuery change function but I want to use the value that was passed through in other functions but it does not get the value for some reason

```
function getTweet(){
  $('#test').change(function() {
    var value = $('#test :selected').val();
  });
}
```

want to use the value outside of the change function but it does not grab it

```
<form>  
    <select id="test">
        <option value="one">1</option>
        <option value="two">2</option>
        <option value="three">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Probably a paste issue that your `getTweet` function is missing the closing `}`?

Comment: yea sorry about that paste issue let me edit

Comment: Please elaborate on "pass a variable after a user selects" as we my be able to better help you.

Comment: It works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/2xEqT/

Comment: @Ian of course it works well *inside* the change handler :)

Comment: @Jack It works anywhere... I'm not saying it's right - I know your solution is the best/easiest way, but there should be nothing wrong with the OP's code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the most current value of the drop-down anywhere in your code, you can just reference it like this:

```
$('#test').val()
```

I've removed the `:selected`, because that's not necessary; `.val()` will give the right value.

Answer (score -1):

You might use custom events to do something based on that event?

Example:

```
$('#test').change(function () {
    $('mysubscriberselectorshere').trigger('gettweet');
});

// do something based on the custom event
$('mysubscriberselectorshere').on('gettweet', function {
    // do good stuff here
    alert($('#test').val());
});
```